# Injection of HttpServletRequest in Jersey POST handler

Tags: java, rest, jersey

Consider this case:-
I am injecting HttpServletRequest in a Rest Service like

```
@Context
HttpServletRequest request;
```

And use it in a method like:-

```
@GET
@Path("/simple")
public Response handleSimple() {
    System.out.println(request.getParameter("myname"));
    return Response.status(200).entity("hello.....").build();

}
```

This works fine but when I try to send it through POST method and replace the @GET by @POST annotation, I get the parameter value null.

Please suggest me where I am mistaking.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to get your parameters etc out of the request. The JAX-RS impl. handles that for you.

You have to use the parameter annotations to map your parameters to method parameters. Casting converting etc. is done automaticly.

Here your method using three differnt ways to map your parameter:

```
// As Pathparameter
@POST
@Path("/simple/{myname}")
public Response handleSimple(@PathParam("myname") String myName) {
    System.out.println(myName);
    return Response.status(200).entity("hello.....").build();
}

// As query parameter
@POST
@Path("/simple")
public Response handleSimple(@QueryParam("myname") String myName) {
    System.out.println(myName);
    return Response.status(200).entity("hello.....").build();
}

// As form parameter
@POST
@Path("/simple")
public Response handleSimple(@FormParam("myname") String myName) {
    System.out.println(myName);
    return Response.status(200).entity("hello.....").build();
}
```

Documentation about JAX-RS Annotations from Jersey you can find here:
https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html

Comment: what if I have more than about 20 parameters like that?

Comment: You can build up very complex parameters with @BeanParameter or you use old tricks like [] brakets in your param names to let them be transported as a kind of an array, which you can also map on an array. Be creative to find a solution. There are endless possibilities with that annotations in JAX-RS.